# IIS 8 is not rewriting

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have the very simple following rewrite rule (on my IIS default web site) (ARR and Url rewrite are installed, I use IIS 8)

```
<rule name="git" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*://git.mydomain.com/?.*" />
    <conditions>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:10080/" />
</rule>
```

the https offload option is disabled.

- https://localhost:10080/ is online
- https://git.mydomain.com:10080/ is online

I tryed without https (that is with http), but "nothing rewrite" 
but I always finish on IIS default web page.

I can't figure out what else to try.

---

finally the `url` condition applies on :

> Url path after '/'

so the correct rule is:

```
<rule name="git" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="git\.mydomain\.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:10080/{R:0}" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1.

Comment: @LexLi I just have to figure out what `Happend query string` means as I have to use {R:0} in my action...